# Sed script to modify path

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file generated with

`declare -r app_classpath="/home/ubuntu/path1:$lib_dir/../` ...

I want to append the app_classpath with another path after the first quotation and ending with a colon.

Comment: Could you clarify a little? Your question mentions sed, but in what way would you like to use it to append here?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sed -i.bak -e '/^declare -r app_classpath=/ s|"|"/home/ubuntu/path2:|' file
```

What it does:

- The first `/^declare .../` locates the lines beginning with "declare ..."
- On those lines, the `s` command substitutes the `"` with `"your_path:`
- the `-i` flag makes a backup copy of your original file